# Can you create a Youtube Playlist with python only using the VideoIds?

Tags: python-3.x, list, playlist, spotipy

I've been using the ytmusicapi lately. It is not an official API from youtube. I coded a little script In python it creates a new Playlist and it returns its ID. If I put the id in the URL like this: [https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list="ID"](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=%22ID%22) it says there is no such Playlist.

Here is my code:

```
from ytmusicapi import YTMusic
from spotify import getPlaylistSong

songs = getPlaylistSong('0LJfazkTRxGhcW0ONiN24q')

ytmusic = YTMusic('headers_auth.json')
playlistid = ytmusic.create_playlist(title="test", description="...")
x = ytmusic.search(songs[0], limit=1)[0]['videoId']

videoIds = [x]

ytLink = 'https://music.youtube.com/watch?v='

for s in songs:
    try:
        videoIds.append(ytmusic.search(s, limit=1)[0]['videoId'])
    except:
      print("no Id!")

list = []

for i in videoIds:
    list.append(ytLink + i)



playlist = ytmusic.add_playlist_items(playlistId=playlistid, videoIds=videoIds)

print(playlistid)
```

Basically the id doesn't work :(